# Как лучше всего сверстать такой блок?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше всего сверстать данный блок? Он находиться на стыке первой секции и второй. Пробовал задать секции position:relative, блоку абсолют, но тогда появляется проблема с центрированием, + значение max-width не работает для этого блока в таком случаи, и приходиться задавать фиксированную ширину, в процентах тоже нельзя, т.к. опять же абсолют. В общем вопрос, как сделать этот блок, что бы он имел относительную ширину и что бы он всегда находился по центру на любых экранах?

Comment: Это вам не тостер, тут нужно не прости вопрос задать, а показать как вы пытались решить задачу, разметить код своих попыток.

Comment: Отрицательный margin поможет решить эту проблему

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант тебя устроит?
https://jsfiddle.net/och4zcfm/

Основной момент: надо чтобы левый, правый и центральный блоки были внутри одного родителя. После этого легко можно центральный блок спозиционировать.

Есть один момент - в моем примере я знаю ширину центрального блока.
Если она неизвестна- надо добавить еще один блок, внутрь которого разместить центральный блок и добавить свойство `text-align: center` и `display: inline-block`

https://jsfiddle.net/och4zcfm/1/